# How to imply the format-like picture with LaTeX?

Tags: easylist

[image]

How to imply the format-like picture?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Generally, it's good practice here to post a minimal compilable document showing what you've tried so far, and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have, though people tend to help out as much as they can anyway. (See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.)

Comment: Also, please consider your choice of tags next time. [If you find the answer below useful, you should accept it.]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\textbf{The Top-$k$ Maximal Cliques Problem}\\
\textbf{Input:} an uncertain graph~$G$ and positive integers~$k$ and~$s$.\\
\textbf{Output:} a collection~$\mathcal{F}$ of $k$ vertex sets of $g$ such that

\end{document}
```

[image: output]